# Limit AJAX calls in select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a `select` element with about 15000 options (select is populated with a database call). Select2 (version 4.0.6) is used on the element, to allow for filtering. However, since having that many options on the page isn't the brightest idea, I want to implement limited AJAX calls.

By limited, I mean that I want the AJAX to be triggered if the user types in a term which is 3 to 5 characters long. If the user keeps typing after that, ordinary select2 filter kicks in, and no AJAX calls are made.

So, I've tried using something like this:

```
$('#clientFilter').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "ajax/ajax-filter.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        delay: 250,
        cache: false,
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        maximumInputLength: 5,
        data: function(params) {
            if(params.term) {
                if(params.term.trim().length >=3 && params.term.trim().length <=5) {
                    var query = {
                        selText: params.term
                    }
                    return query;
                }
            }
        },
        processResults: function(data) {
            return {
                results: console.log(data)
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But this not working as I expect it to - the AJAX is actually triggered, and that's something I don't want. Sure, I can check the input length on the server, but I'd rather not pass anything to the server if the original condition (3-5 characters) is not met.

What am I doing wrong, and which direction should I take from here? Do I have to place AJAX in the initialization of select2, or can I turn it into a function, and call that function outside of select2 initialization?

Comment: I don't believe you can do what you are attempting with Select2. You can configure it to either use AJAX or work on local data, not a hybrid of both.